# Install Magisk on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935FD) UAE ROM

Tags: magisk

Going quietly mad here... have tried and tried. Steps taken are
I purchased a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge online - its an SM-G935FD, with an original ROM (official) from the UAE (XSG).
I install TWRP - no problems there - then install Magisk Manager on the phone via the website.
I download Magisk also, and then boot into recovery with TWRP.
I install Magisk, but after rebooting, I get the following message - 
"Verification failed" "Unable to restart your device. The integrity verification has failed. You need to reset your device to factory default settings. This will erase all your data"
Any ideas or suggestions as to what I should do with this? I rooted to phone, and have lost access to Samsung Health, which I'd like to use. I don't need Samsung Pay.
Any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you set **OEM Unlocking** ON in Dev Options and unlocked bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.
I finally solved my issue late last night. In recovery, using TWRP, after trying to install Magisk, I'd get a response that was something like "unable to mount /data partition"..and I believe that was what was causing the issue. I found this html site at XDA developers

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-data-t3830897

which steps you through the process of repairing the data file systems (both ext2 and ext4), and that worked. Magisk installed correctly and is now working with my banking details, as well as Samsung Health (which involved changing a digit in the System/build prop file (tima from 1 to 0).

Now if someone could show me what to do when the next samsung update comes along, I'd be grateful. Don't want to lose it all (Magisk install) after the next update...

Comment: Looks like found the (partial) solution to your own issue which is great! However, it seems you also accidentally created a duplicate account. Please follow [this help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to regain the ownership of your previous account and the question so you can comment on the question & accept the answer. Thanks!